# Updating association with cast_assoc

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have two tables `Users` and `Companies`. User belongs to a Company and a Company has many users.

I have a form, where i can add user to the company which is implemented as a nested form(`inputs_for`), so in the company's changeset, I have called `cast_assoc`

```
def changeset(company, attrs) do
    company
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :email])
    |> validate_required([:name, :email])
    |> cast_assoc(:users, with: &User.company_admin_changeset/2)
  end
```

What I want to do is, when I add a already existing user to a company, it should update the user's company_id(foreign_key). If the user doesnt exists, just create one.

Looking at my requirement, I am starting to think that it is not possible to do it from cast_assoc. So, I have used `transaction`

```
  def create_company(attrs \\ %{}) do
    Repo.transaction(fn ->
      cmp =
        Company.changeset(%Company{}, %{name: attrs["name"], email: attrs["email"]})
        |> Repo.insert!()

      Enum.each(attrs["users"], fn {_, user} ->
        case Accounts.get_user_by_email(user["email"]) do
          nil ->
            User.company_admin_changeset(%User{}, %{email: user["email"], company_id: cmp.id})
            |> Repo.insert!()

          account ->
            account |> Ecto.Changeset.change(company_id: cmp.id) |> Repo.update!()
        end
      end)
    end)
  end
```

but if it is possible can you tell me how I can do it?

Comment: I think your approach is correct -- your use case doesn't appear to fall into those described by the association's `:on_replace` option.  You could, however, probably clean up your flow a bit to take advantage of `Ecto.Repo.get_by/3` and `Ecto.Repo.insert_or_update/2`

Answer (score 1):

I used upserts but I had to run custom methods depending upon wether the user existed or not so I am still using my old code with transaction